# Placing menu items horizontally

Tags: android, menu

Hi in the below I was implemented the left navigation drawer with and header and menu items.Want to display menu items are home,setting,trash,logout.

Want to display menu items horizontally .
can any one help me how to display menu items horizontally with the below menu items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/trash"
            android:title="History"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_trash"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:title="Logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

activity_main:

```
  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Use navigation drawer

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I am using navigation drawer

Comment: So attach your full code please

Comment: You can use bottom navigation

Comment: left drawer I am displaying not displaying bottom navigation drawee

Comment: Horizontal in left drawer?!

Answer (score 0):

add this line in you XML

`app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"`

into an item, where `action_layout` is the layout that you want to show in horizontal orientation, for example:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
android:title="layout"
app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout" />
```

This will be your modified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:title="History"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_trash"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit"/>
</group>
</menu>
```